# How to know input 's attribute when document loaded with javascript

Tags: javascript

I really need to know the input's attribute when document had finished loading. For example:

```
<input type="text" data-type="string" />
<input type="text" data-type="string" />
<input type="text" data-type="date" />
```

And with javascript with an alert should display

```
you have 2 string data-type and 1 date data-type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the risk of being slated for giving you too much code... given that your question hasn't been tagged `jQuery` a pure Javascript implementation could be as follows:

```
(function(){
    var loader = window.onload;
    window.onload = function(){
        if(typeof loader == 'function') loader();
        var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), data = [];
        for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
            var type = els[i].getAttribute('data-type') || 'unknown';
            if(typeof data[type] == 'undefined') data[type] = 1;
            else data[type]++;
        }
        var out = '';
        for(var key in data){
            if(out != '') out += 'and '; else out += 'You have ';
            out += data[key] + ' ' + key + ' data-type ';
        }
        alert(out);
    }
})();
```

Somewhat more convoluted and perhaps confusing - but should you post any further questions please include code examples of **what you have tried** and state where exactly you are fuzzy.

Comment: yeah, thats it worked well and thanks for that advice, ill keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

with Jquery.

```
$.each( $("input") , function(_index, _item){    
    alert($(_item).attr("data-type"));
});
```

you just now have to count and display your message...

Comment: for complex data you can use `$(_item).data('type')` [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/2033671)